# Cannot launch 64 bit Windows version of application : org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid -> NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, osgi

The complete version of the problem, entire log file can be found at this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1577489/#msg_1577489)

We have a Eclipse application whose 64 bit windows version fails to launch. While its 32 bit windows version, 32 and 64 bit mac version and 32 and 64 bit linux version work well.

I am using `eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64`

I have referred the following links:-
[Link_A](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/488516/)
[Link_B](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/314656/)
[Link_C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786043/launching-eclipse-application-with-java-web-start-generates-java-lang-classnotfo)

But they are not helpful to me as either they revert back to 32 bit system instead of 64 bit system. `I need to get the 64bit version of the application working`. In the other link they add missing SWT jar. I checked my target platform[Windows->Preferences->Plug-in Development->Target Platforms  -> Edit -> type swt in type filter text]. And I see SWT library checked or included

`Any attempts to run the 64 bit version of the application by double clicking the application fails to launch and generates the following exception in the log.` I am pasting here starting part of my log file. As the entire log file shall not fit in here

```
!SESSION 2015-01-20 13:49:43.986 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-20 13:49:45.107
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (73).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

I shall appreciate any help resolving this issue

Comment: The 'AbstractBundle' class show in the stack trace only exists in Eclipse 3.x, so this does not appear to have been built using an Eclipse 4.4 target platform.

Comment: @greg-449 I am using eclipse luna 64 bit 4.4 version. not sure why it shows AbstractBundle in the log file. I am building it using TYCHO, a maven plugin

Comment: @greg-449 The entire log file is present at this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1577489/#msg_1577489)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it resolved with the help of guys at eclipse forum. For detailed explanation check the [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1577489/#msg_1577489)

Solution:-

The 64 bit org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 bundle was not getting included in the target osgi environment.

A quick test was to open osgi shell for the application

Command:- `application.exe -noExit -console`

Once you are in the osgi shell, execute the command `ss org.eclipse.swt`

```
osgi> ss org.eclipse.swt

Framework is launched.

id      State       Bundle
70      RESOLVED    org.eclipse.swt_3.7.2.v3740f
                    Fragments=71
71      RESOLVED    org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f
                    Master=70
```

If equinox(OSGI container) does not include 64 bit SWT bundle, you shall not see
`71      RESOLVED    org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f Master=70`in the above command prompt.

I finally noticed for `Target platform's equinox environment`, in my `feature.xml` plugin specification for `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` and `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64` were not included.

In the feature.xml file had to include the following

```
<plugin
         id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64"
         os="win32"
         ws="win32"
         arch="x86_64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64"
         os="win32"
         ws="win32"
         arch="x86_64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"/>
```

Once I included them, the project ran fine